# I want to re-ask the user to enter another command after they asked it once, but I don't know how

Tags: python-3.x

I'm coding a 'coding language' using python and I want to be able to enter multiple commands but when I enter one command it just stops and doesn't let me re-ask a command, What code would fix this?

I've tried using while loops but that didn't work at all. Here's an example:

```
x = ''
x = input("enter x")
if x == 'hi':
    print("yay")
    (I want to reask it from here now)
```

Comment: How come your while loop didn't work at all? Can you post the code that didn't work? -- because a while loop is the solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok I did it and when I redefine my loop variable it says invalid syntax but I did i = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a while loop with a condition if you don't know how many times you want to ask for a new command. Here an example that will stop asking when the input is 'quit'

```
x = ''
while x != 'quit':
    x = input(">> ")
    if x == 'hi':
        print("yay")
```